# Does it matter which side of Basel airport I rent my car in?

Tags: car-rentals, bsl

I'm flying into Basel from Paris to stay on the Swiss side.  Does it matter whether I rent a car in Euros (presumably French side) or Francs (Swiss side)?

Comment: The use of swiss highways require a paid badge on the car. The swiss side cars will probably have it whereas the french side ones will probably not.

Answer (score 5):

Last time I was there, it was very easy to go from one side to the other (that's not the case in Geneva for example) and I can't imagine it has become more difficult recently, with Schengen and everything. So you can choose the side that's more convenient for you.

Things to be mindful of:

- Swiss motorway vignette: Swiss cars are more likely to have it.
- Insurance/regulations: Car hire firms have all sorts of restrictions on border crossing. Switzerland/France is likely to be OK in both directions but do check the terms of the contract.
- Customs: If you are importing expensive goods, lots of cash, alcohol, tobacco, etc. crossing the Swiss/French border means more paperwork.

Incidentally, the exchange rate will be unattractive but you could probably also rent a Swiss car and be charged in euros if you wish.